# ADF pipeline is getting triggered without waiting for file to upload to ADLS

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have multiple files in ADLS location. There is a ADF pipeline which takes files to other location after some transformation. The issue is files are big in size, they are taking time to load to ADLS. But the pipeline is not waiting files to completely load to the adls. It is getting triggered with half data in the files.

What can i do to make pipeline wait untill whole file got copied completely?

Comment: I haven't worked with blob triggers before. I don't know your constraints, but I suggest you get the process that uploads blobs do the following: 1. Copy into ADLS in "copyinprogress" folder 2. Once copy is complete, move the blob file from "copyinprogress" to "waiting". The second copy step inside ADLS should complete really quickly. Make sure that ADF triggers off the "waiting" folder. This of course relies on you being able to add a step to the publishing process

Answer (score 0):

If your file size is big, take a note of time for the file to load. Add a **wait activity** before the dataflow activity and give time in seconds here.

[image]

Wait activity will wait till the mentioned time completes and your file will be loaded in this time. Then dataflow activity will be executed with total data.

Comment: Hi Rakesh, thanks for you response. This can help  but in some cases file size won't be big, in those cases it's not good to make pipeline wait. Is there any solution where I can check wether files is completely loaded then only start the pipeline?

Comment: AFAIK, in ADF it might not be possible to check whether the file is completely uploaded or not. I think you can give a try as suggested by @Nick.Mc in comments.